# DBSCAN evaluation - need true_labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am trying to follow this example with some data of my own: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my 'labels_true' variable as part of the evaluation of the DBSCAN predictions.

Here is the line that first requires it:

```
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
```

I have data with latitude & longitude columns, which I am using as follows:

```
coords = X_train.as_matrix(columns=['latitude', 'longitude'])

kms_per_radian = 6371.0088
epsilon = 1.5 / kms_per_radian
db = DBSCAN(eps=epsilon, min_samples=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine').fit(np.radians(coords))
cluster_labels = db.labels_
num_clusters = len(set(cluster_labels))
clusters = pd.Series([coords[cluster_labels == n] for n in range(num_clusters)])
print num_clusters
#get returned 60
```

and

```
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(coords, cluster_labels))
```

is the line that doesn't work for me.

X_train.head():

```
bathrooms   bedrooms    building_id     description     features    interest_level  latitude    longitude   manager_id  price
10  1.5     3.0     53a5b119ba8f7b61d4e010512e0dfc85    A Brand New 3 Bedroom 1.5 bath ApartmentEnjoy ...   []  medium  40.7145     -73.9425    5ba989232d0489da1b5f2c45f6688adc    3000.0
10000   1.0     2.0     c5c8a357cba207596b04d1afd1e4f130        [Doorman, Elevator, Fitness Center, Cats Allow...   low     40.7947     -73.9667    7533621a882f71e25173b27e3139d83d    5465.0
100004  1.0     1.0     c3ba40552e2120b0acfc3cb5730bb2aa    Top Top West Village location, beautiful Pre-w...   [Laundry In Building, Dishwasher, Hardwood Flo...   high    40.7388     -74.0018    d9039c43983f6e564b1482b273bd7b01    2850.0
100007  1.0     1.0     28d9ad350afeaab8027513a3e52ac8d5    Building Amenities - Garage - Garden - fitness...   [Hardwood Floors, No Fee]   low     40.7539     -73.9677    1067e078446a7897d2da493d2f741316    3275.0
100013  1.0     4.0     0   Beautifully renovated 3 bedroom flex 4 bedroom...   [Pre-War]   low     40.8241     -73.9493    98e13ad4b495b9613cef886d79a6291f    3350.0
```

As I understand, db.labels_ are the predicted cluster # that each point belongs too. I would like to return a new coords array with the predicted 60 cluster labels, and another for the metrics with the true 60 cluster labels, in place of the old latitude/longitude for each point.

Comment: See [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation) and look for metrics which dont require ground truth data.

Answer (score 0):

db.labels_ are the predicted labels, but the 'homogeneity_score' function requires that you compare the ground truth labels prior to clustering to the predicted clusters.

You are misusing the function by using the full training set as the 'labels_true' input into the score function. If you have labeled training data then include just the ground truth labels as the 'labels_true' input. If you do not have the ground truth label for your training data then you cannot use the 'homogeneity_score' function.

Answer (score 0):

In *reality* you don't have `true_labels` when doing clustering.

So you can't use homogeneity etc. then.

This only works for "demonstration" datasets. If you *had* labels, you would use classification rather than clustering.